# Globally available Angular functions using $scope variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm dealing with a simple problem in AngularJS regarding the visibility of functions between controllers and the $scope and $rootScope variables.

To clarify, I have a couple of functions in several of my controllers **that I would like to make available in all of them** (*for the sake of code clarity and avoid duplicating functions*).

I already have functions using $rootScope and services for other functionalities, but I can't find the proper way to address this case.

This is one example, one simple function to toggle an accordion list (Source: http://codepen.io/deinerson1/pen/gxnzj)

```
// Toggle groups
$scope.toggleGroup = function(group) {
    if ($scope.isGroupShown(group)) {
        $scope.shownGroup = null;
    } else {
        $scope.shownGroup = group;
    }
};
$scope.isGroupShown = function(group) {
    return $scope.shownGroup === group;
};
```

In this case, how can I make this function (*that is using $scope*) available to all the controllers that may want to use it?

*As a summary:*

**What is the proper way of making functions available globally, including those using $scope variable?**

1. If I use a function inside $rootScope, how can I access/handle the $scope variable that is being used inside that function?
2. Exactly the same question if I use a service.
3. And last but not least, **what might be the correct/best way** of handling this situation if the previous two options are discarded?

*Also, to have another example and avoid getting stuck with the simple accordion thing:*

```
$scope.cancelModal = function() {
    $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
        disableBack: true
    });
    $ionicViewSwitcher.nextDirection('back'); // Go back effect
    $state.go('app.main');
}
```

Comment: create a factory,define functions inside this factory and then inject that factory name to every controller.

Comment: I would definitely use a factory for that no doubt

Comment: But how to define a factory with multiple functions?

And also, how to handle $scope inside that factory?